# 16.04 - Lenovo Yoga Accessing Disk Constantly

Tags: disk-usage, memory-usage

I have a new Yoga machine with 8GB memory. The technician took off windows and put on Ubuntu 16.04. It all works fine. But the disk is constantly being accessed. I tried free -h

```
free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.3G        3.4G        1.8G        200M        2.1G        3.4G
Swap:          7.5G          0B        7.5G
```

I have no big processing but I have a lot of software installed for blockchain work. I have 1TB of storage. I was wondering what can I do. It all started when I tried running android studio. I had to turn on Virtualization using F2 and changing the BIOS. I set the BIOS back now and I am not using Android. When I was running Android the machine was dead slow.

The disk is annoying with its noise. I would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: You can use `iotop` to see what keeps the hdd busy. Install it if needed, and then in a terminal: `sudo iotop -o`.

Comment: Tried iotop -o and jbd2 comes up a lot. I will check this.

Comment: I saw a lot of comments complaining about jbd2 and high io. There was no real consistent solution. Also mostly the comments were from years ago.